# How to loop through a table and set variables based on the existence (or not) of data in those tables?

Tags: templating, forloop, fieldtypes

I am using a table field in Craft (`price`) limited to one row only, used to manage price setting in different currencies on an entry. The three cols each contain number fields with the handles `dkk`, `euro`, and `usd` respectively. (**note** their column order here can be used to infer a preference later which is useful)

At the template level I am also setting a variable `pricepreferredCurrency` to specify the currency we want to use for conversions when required. This could be moved to the cp later I guess but it's barcoded at the template level for now.

```
{% set preferredCurrency = euro %}
```

If at minimum one price is set I would like to display the price in all three currencies, but I am struggling to create template logic needed to (smartly) support the following functions:

- If any price is *explicitly* set, use that price and do not unset or
  recalculate the price based on other prices or currencies. Just take the input at face value.
- Otherwise, if a price is empty or unset but at least one other price is set, use the next available price that *is* set as the price to convert from (using `preferredCurrency` as the basis for that conversion)
- If no prices in any currencies are set, exit and show no prices.

I have already worked out the conversion between currencies, but I am having trouble looping through and making good decisions and logic to handle the different cases. If I can get to the cases I can handle the rest I think.

I feel like this is probably very simple and could even be abstracted I am sure to loop through an expanded set of currencies (without the need to get explicit) but that is beyond me.

I am also open to completely other ways of doing this in craft. Maybe it is better to move currencies into a category group.

I think ultimately I will make decisions about which price to show based on some geolocation, but now I am ready to calculate (where needed) and surface all three. Your help/advice as always much appreciated.

You can see I started to work through this and could immediately tell I was off on the wrong foot. This is really embarrassing to share but...

```
{% for row in entry.price %}
{% set preferredCurrency = DKK %}

{% set priceDKK = row.dkk %}
{% set priceEURO = row.euro %}
{% set priceUSD = row.usd %}

{% if row.dkk is not empty %}
  {% set priceDKK = row.dkk %}
{% elseif priceEURO is not empty %}
  {% set priceEURO = row.euro %}
  {# abort - it is here I realized this is some dead-end foolery #}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well. It's not pretty but it works. That improvements could be made on this is both certain and welcome.

```
{# Check to see if we've for got prices set, Set them if we do... #}

{% set priceDKK = entry.price[0].DKK ? entry.price[0].DKK : false %}
{% set priceEUR = entry.price[0].EUR ? entry.price[0].EUR : false %}
{% set priceUSD = entry.price[0].USD ? entry.price[0].USD : false %}

{# Figure out which price and rate we have to calc with... #}
{# Create our var before the loop (because scope)... #}

{% set basePrice = "" %}

{# We work down the list looking for our first set price #}
{# We will set it as our base price #}
{# We are going to convert all prices to DKK first #}

{% for price in entry.price %}
  {% if priceDKK %}
    {% set basePrice = priceDKK / rateDKK %}
  {% elseif priceEUR %}
    {% set basePrice = priceEUR / rateEUR %}
  {% elseif priceUSD %}
    {% set basePrice = priceUSD / rateUSD %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{# Calculate prices if they don't exist... #}
{# We do not calc prices that were manually set... #}

{% for price in entry.price %}
  {% if not priceDKK %}
    {% set priceDKK = basePrice * rateDKK | round(-3,'ceil') %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if not priceEUR %}
    {% set priceEUR = (basePrice * rateEUR) | round(-3,'ceil') %}
  {% endif %}

  {% if not priceUSD %}
    {% set priceUSD = (basePrice * rateUSD) | round(-3,'ceil') %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{# end #}
```